# laravel 5.7 : paginate with unique data

Tags: laravel

I want create a query that sort by desc after it get unique event_name (i have many same name in my table but i want show one of them) and after it i want to paginate it
i tried this

```
DB::table('events')->latest()->get()->unique('event_name');
```

but i cant paginate it because its a collection

i tried this

```
Event::order By("created_at","DESC")->paginate(6)->all();
```

but i cant unique data

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Event::distinct('event_name')->orderby("created_at","DESC")->paginate(6);
```

Comment: sure just after in 3 mins

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Event::orderBy("created_at","DESC")->distinct('event_name')->paginate(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this?

```
Event::groupBy('event_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Calc total rows (pgsql)

#### Install

```
composer require larahook/distinct-on-pagination
```

#### Usage

Add `DistinctOnPagination` trait in `SomeModel`

```php
use DistinctOnPagination;
```

- Call your ORM model with `distinct(['field_a', 'field_b'])` and `paginate($perPage)`.
- Total must be calc without Exception

```sql
SomeModel::select(['*'])
    ->distinct(['field_a', 'field_b'])
    ->orderBy('field_a')
    ->orderBy('field_b')
    ->paginate($perPage)
```